# Server error: ReferenceError (localstorage) is not defined (Nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage, referenceerror

I have a category name stored in my localstorage. I understand that with nextjs, localstorage is only stored on the browser, and not in the server side. I've tried this thanks to what I have read of stackoverflow questions with similar issues, but I'm still getting `ReferenceError: selectedCategoryName is not defined`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const sets = () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){
        let selectedCategoryName = localStorage.getItem('selectedCategoryName');
        console.log(selectedCategoryName)
    }
    return (
        <div className="title">
            <h2>{selectedCategoryName}</h2> //server error
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've also tried this instead of the if statement (not confident this is right anyway), but same error:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    const categoryNameTitle = localStorage.get('selectedCategoryName');

    if(categoryNameTitle) {
      setMyState((prev) => ({ ...prev, selectedCategoryName: JSON.parse(categoryNameTitle)}))
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an undefined `selectedCategoryName` because it only exists in the scope of your `if(...){...}` block.

The code below should works better:

```
const sets = () => {
  const selectedCategoryName = typeof window !== 'undefined' 
    ? localStorage.getItem('selectedCategoryName') 
    : undefined;
  console.log(selectedCategoryName)
   
  return (
    <div className="title">
      <h2>{selectedCategoryName}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using "localstorage" somewhere else. Read the error message carefully.

```
ReferenceError (localstorage) is not defined
```

it is not saying  `localStorage` with capital "S" it says `localstorage` with lowercase "s". looks like you used `localstorage` somewhere else which is `undefined`

or when you write this

```
let selectedCategoryName = localStorage.getItem('selectedCategoryName');
```

localStorage has no 'selectedCategoryName' record. you conditionally set with ternary operator

```
let selectedCategoryName = localStorage.getItem('selectedCategoryName') ? localStorage.getItem('selectedCategoryName') :
"this data does not exist"
```

You should also set the state globally so other parts in your component can access `selectedCategoryName`

```
const [selectedCategoryName,setSelectedCategoryName]=useState("")
```